# parse_ini_string () from function as GLOBAL variable?

Tags: php, global-variables, ini

how this should be correctly syntaxed?

```
<?php 

    $settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini", true);

    function testing() { return $GLOBALS[$settings['Language']['lang']]; }

    echo testing();

?>
```

please note that stating `$settings` must be above custom functions as its used by many many functions, requires etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `$settings` parameter to the function like so:

```
<?php 
 function testing($settings) { return $GLOBALS[$settings['Language']['lang']]; }

 $settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini", true);
 echo testing($settings);
?>
```

Comment: or even better to declare  $GLOBALS['settings'] = $settings as first thing inside the function